# Noether's Normalization Lemma

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In trying to understand the attached proof of Noether's Normalization lemma, I am having trouble with the induction step. How do we know that the transcendence degree of S is still n? Thanks in advance.

[image: Noether's Normalization Lemma Proof]

Comment: I think I recognize this as the retyping of Mumford's Red Book. Note that by the time this was done Mumford had no interest in algebraic geometry and the book is riddled with typos introduced by whomever redid everything in LaTeX, so one has to be careful. If you can get a copy of the first edition from the library I think that's helpful.

Comment: This, on the other hand, doesn't look to be one of those typos. $R$ is integral over $S$ and hence on quotient fields $K(R)$ is algebraic over $K(S)$, so these have the same transcendence degree over $k$. Does that argument make sense to you?

Comment: You're concluding that R and S have the same transcendence degree over k?

Comment: Yes. If the transcendence degree were somehow smaller for $S$ so I had a polynomial ring $A = k[x_1, \dots, x_m] \subset K(S)$ and $K(A) \subset K(S)$ algebraic then $K(R)$ is algebraic over $K(A)$ and that doesn't make sense. Hopefully I'm not gliding over something important.

Comment: I think I follow for the most part, thanks! Just a few questions: (1) In your last comment, {X1,...,Xm} is a transcendence basis with m less than the transcendence degree of R? (2) Your notation K(R) is equivalent to the field of fractions of R (an integral domain) as an algebra over k correct?

Comment: Ah, yeah; I meant to write all of these things but got lazy.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the help!